# Date subtraction in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following dates that I get from database as well as from php `date`. I did some formatting to the date from database to suit accordingly. Those are as follows

From database

```
 $startDate = $tagQueryRows['startDate'];
 $startDate = strtotime($startDate);
 $startDate = date( 'd-m-Y', $startDate );
```

Take note that the `startDate` in database is in this format `2019-09-02 10:26:44`

From php `date`

```
$todayDate = date('d-m-Y');
```

Then I did a subtraction as follows

```
$totalDaysCompleted = ($todayDate- $startDate);
```

When I did this, it shows the correct number of days but with warning

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Thus I edited my code as below

```
$totalDaysCompleted = (strtotime(str_replace('-','/',$todayDate)) - strtotime(str_replace('-','/',$startDate)));
```

This time the warning gone, but it is not showing the `$totalDaysCompleted` correctly. The `$totalDaysCompleted` should be a number like 1, 2, 3 etc. But now it is showing weird number such as -150000 etc.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't subtract formatted dates. You should keep them in timestamp format and use that. Or use `DateTime` objects.

Comment: It's especially wrong in `d-m-Y` format, even after you remove the hypens. Why would you expect `19122019 - 18122019` return `1`? And why would replacing hyphens with slash make it any better?

Comment: I did that way from some other stackoverflow post to avoid month and date mix up. Anyway it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and errors, I got it right by doing the following way

```
$startDate = $tagQueryRows['startDate'];
$startDate = strtotime($startDate);
$todayDate = date('d-m-Y');
$totalDaysCompleted = (strtotime($todayDate)) - $startDate;
$totalDaysCompleted = round($totalDaysCompleted/(60*60*24),0);
```